# Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I've had a look at the other similar questions but the issues were syntax errors.  Perhaps I'm missing something but my syntax looks correct as far as I can tell.
I'm trying to declare a method as follows:

```
internal IDictionary<string, T> FillObjects(
    IReadableRange<T> svc,
    Func<T, string> getKey) where T : BaseEntity
{
}
```

but am getting the compiler error:

> constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations

any ideas?

thanks

Matt

Comment: Add type parameter to the method `FillObjects<T>(...)`.

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that your method does not define the generic type `<T>`. It just uses the type `T` given by the enclosing type.

And you can declare constraints only at [the same place where you define generic parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

**There are two solutions:**

**1.**, You should either define generic parameters on the function:

```
public class EnclosingType
{
    internal IDictionary<string, T> FillObjects<T>(
        IReadableRange<T> svc,
        Func<T, string> getKey) where T : BaseEntity
    {
    }
}
```

In your case it doesn't compile, because you `EnclosingType` is probably the `EnclosingType<T>`  that leads to an ambiguity between `EnclosingType's` `T` and `FillObjects'` `T`:

**2.**, Or you could just define the constraints on the enclosing type:

```
public class EnclosingType<T>
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    internal IDictionary<string, T> FillObjects(
         IReadableRange<T> svc,
         Func<T, string> getKey)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are missing the declaration of `T` (your generic type) in the method name. If it isn't declared inside the encapsulating class, you have to declare it explicitly:

```
internal IDictionary<string, T> FillObjects<T>(
    IReadableRange<T> svc,
    Func<T, string> getKey) where T : BaseEntity
{
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The constrain needs to be in same place as the generic parameter. So if `<T>` is part of the class, constrain needs to be part of the whole.

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : BaseEntity
```

or as part of method:

```
T GenericMethod<T>(T param) where T : BaseEntity
```

You cannot create constrain for just one method in generic class, that would not make sense.

Answer (score 4):

If `T` is not a generic type parameter of the parent class of `FillObjects` then you need to specify generic type parameters directly on the method, like so:

```
internal IDictionary<string, T> FillObjects<T>(
    IReadableRange<T> svc,
    Func<T, string> getKey) where T : BaseEntity
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably `T` is the generic argument of your class. You should apply the constraint to your class parameter.

Or if you want this `T` to be independent from the class then re-declare in your method it as other answers says.